# How do I do matrix computations in python without rounding?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some integer matrices of moderate size (a few hundred rows). I need to solve equations of the form `Ax = b` where `b` is a standard basis vector and `A` is one of my matrices. I have been using `numpy.linalg.lstsq` for this purpose, but the rounding errors end up being too significant.

How can I carry out an exact symbolic computation?

(PS I don't really need the code to be efficient; I'm more concerned about ease of coding.)

Comment: If your input is finite floating point then it's hard to see how exact arithmetic could help

Comment: No, my input is an integer matrix. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Few hundred rows is tiny. Do you have ill conditioning?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I have more rows than columns.

Comment: What makes you think roundoff is a problem?

Comment: Well I know from other approaches what some of the answers should be. In particular all of the answers should be integers. The smaller calculations are very close to the correct integers, so my code is almost certainly correct. Which leaves roundoff error to explain why the larger computations go wrong.

Comment: if you have more rows than columns then, typically, there is no unique solution. Judge the answers by how accurate Ax=b is solved rather than whether or not the solution is integer valued.

Answer (score 2):

If your only option is to use free tools written in python, [sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) might work, but it could well be simpler to use mathematica.

Comment: Mathematica is an option, but the rest of the code is already in python, so it would be best if I didn't have to mix languages. Plus I haven't coded in mathematica for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you're serious about your comment that you require your solution vector to be integer, then you're looking for something called the "integer least squares problem". Which is believed to be NP-hard. There are some heuristic solvers, but it all gets very complicated.

Comment: My solution vector does not need to consist of integers. The goal is to use the solution vectors to calculate some numbers that happen to be integers. Anyway the complexity class of the problem doesn't matter because my matrices are all so small.

Answer (score 0):

The [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) library has support for arbitrary-precision floating-point numbers, and supports matrix algebra: http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/tags/0.17/doc/build/matrices.html

Using `sympy` to do the computation exactly is then a second option.